# Global Picklist Valueset settings does not get updated on doing meta deployment

Tags: apex, global-picklist

I was trying to update setting "Sort values alphabetically, not in the order entered. Values will be displayed alphabetically everywhere."  of existing global picklist valueset, but found that existing global picklist/valueset settings cannot be updated via meta deploy, so had to delete and recreate the field and that's when it worked.

I set the property  in meta file  to following false
Is my finding correct, or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: what version are you doing the deploy with?

Comment: doing the deploy using version 38.0